# What is vector quantization using k-means?

Tags: vector, k-means, descriptor, segment, quantization

First of all, can someone explain what vector quantization is, its purpose, and what it does? Secondly, an explanation of how k-means is used to do this would be appreciated as well.

For the record, I don't know if this will make a difference in the explanation, but I'm trying to learn about vector quantization in the context of boundary descriptors. If I calculated a number of boundary descriptors for a particular segment in an image, and I wanted to vector quantize them using k-means, what would this mean, what would this do, why would I want to do, and how would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Vector quantization is the process of discretizing a random variable valued in some vector space. The result is the projection of that random variable onto a finite set of knots. It is used for signal transmission, quadrature, variance reduction and a lot of other applications.

Optimal quantization consists in choosing the knots in such a way to minimize the mean L^p discretization error.

The K-means is also called Lloyd algorithm consists in starting from an arbitrary set of knots, (or codebook), and iteratively replace each one of them by the L^p-median (or simply by the mean for quadratic quantization) of the probability distribution given that it falls in the Voronoi cell of that knot. An interactive animation is available [here](http://www.quantize.maths-fi.com/lloyds_animation). 
The historical reference on the Lloyd algorithm is the following

Stuart P. Lloyd, *Least squares quantization in PCM*, IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, vol. 28, issue 2, pp. 129–137, 1982

K-means algorithms always decreases the quantization error but does not always converge to the globally optimal quantizer. Although, in the case of one-dimensional log-concave distributions, the algorithm converges to a unique global minimum.

The [optimal quantization web site](http://www.quantize.maths-fi.com/) contains an extensive bibliography on the matter of vector quantization and functional quantization.